# Customizing Bootstrap without touching source code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen tutorials about modifying Bootstrap by overriding existing styles. However, the question I can't seem to wrap my head around is how do I remove certain styles Bootstrap enforces without directly deleting or commenting out that section in the source code?

For example, I don't want to use any of Bootstrap's @media print styles. My current solution is directly commenting out that section. However, I don't think this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: You can always create a new stylesheet and hide/override elements you don't need, but that can be super inefficient. What's wrong with commenting out/deleting code you don't need?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there's no real harm in commenting out styles you don't want to use. But you can also make a custom bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few elements that you want to get rid of, you can override them and cancel their styles from your own stylesheet. Let's say that an element has a `1px solid #ccc` border and that you don't want that, you can override it with `1px solid transparent` (or just `border: none;`)  in your own stylesheet.

That being said, if you have to modify large chunks, then it's a lot easier to just edit the source code, remove what you don't want/need. Or, go the other way around, only add what you want/need to your own CSS if there isn't too much.

Answer (score 0):

You best choice will be to use the LESS (or SASS) version of bootstrap and compile it yourself. Commenting out unneeded parts is then done in bootstrap.less and as simply as:

```
// ...
// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
//@import "print.less";
@import "glyphicons.less";
// ...
```